# How to add the circle, star inside the diamond?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to add the circle inside the diamond, and star inside the circle like in the photo.

[image]

However, using my code,

```
\node[draw, diamond, above=of aux] (diamond) {};
\node[draw,circle,above=of aux,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt]{};
\node[draw, star,above=of aux,minimum size=0.01mm](star){};
```

centers of the circle, diamond and star are not the same as shown in the following picture.

[image]

What's the problem with the code?

Comment: You've already asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98160/how-to-draw-a-star-inside-a-diamond#98164: could you elaborate on the difference between the questions?

Comment: @JosephWright thanks, actually, the older question I have no idea how to do, now I have an idea, but don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @sweetyBaby May I ask you what's the problem with [my comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98160/how-to-draw-a-star-inside-a-diamond#comment211592_98160)?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino actually your comment helps me a lot, however, I don't wish to use (0,0) to locate the center :( Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use the `above` key, just put all the node at the same point.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, fill, star, star points=6, minimum size=5mm] at (0,0){};
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=8mm] at (0,0){};
\node[draw, diamond, minimum size=1.5cm] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**Edit:**
To make the picture smaller, you may either change all `minimum size` keys, or put the whole in a `\resizebox` like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{1cm}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, fill, star, star points=6, minimum size=5mm] at (0,0){};
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=8mm] at (0,0){};
    \node[draw, diamond, minimum size=1.5cm] at (0,0){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

To put all above an (aux) node, you may use:

```
\node[above=of aux,anchor=center] { \resizebox{ ... tikz construction ... } };
```

where `\resizebox{ ... }` is the above construction

Comment: If the `above` refers to another node `(aux)` that is not only auxiliary as the name suggests, than he can’t omit it but add `anchor=center` to align the three nodes at the top of `(aux)` but with their centers. Maybe you like to add this to your answer. An image of the output would be nice too.

Comment: @Tobi It would be nice to show the output, but that would be much easier if the POP provided an MWE.

Comment: @Tobi I've updated my answer by providing a MWE and an output

Comment: @Jake: But doesn’t `above` change the default anchor to `south` as it does in `\path (0,0) node [above] {xx}`?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: +1 for adding the MWE although it’s not your job as Jake said …

Comment: @Tobi: Ah, you're right, sorry. I had tried it out, but put the `anchor=center` before `above=of aux`, which didn't have an effect.

Comment: @Tobi Thanks; I know that it was not directly my job (although I need it to get the output), that why; 1/ I didn't use the positioning library (does the POP really use it?) and 2/ I didn't talk about `aux` node as the POP didn't define it (and, by default, TikZ will use (0,0))

Comment: Thanks, I used above= of aux and anchor=center, it works, however, I wish to make the picuture smaller, thus I change the size, unfortunately, the star is still large, doesn't become smaller, why?