# how to set the size of the star?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I wish to draw the picture described [How to add the circle, star inside the diamond?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98217/how-to-add-the-circle-star-inside-the-diamond)

I tried the code:

```
\node[draw, fill, star, star points=6, minimum size=0.1mm,above=of aux, anchor=center]{};
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=5mm,above=of aux, anchor=center]{};
\node[draw, diamond, minimum size=0.7cm,above=of aux,anchor=center](diamond){};
```

However, the star and the circle is too large, I wish to make them smaller so that it don't touch each other. I tried to set the size to smaller number, however, it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I've already answered in your previous question

Comment: @LionelMANSUY yes, Your answer runs well,however, when I change the size of the star, circle and diamond, it becomes strange. So I am not sure where is the problem.

Comment: Use `\resizebox` (it will always work) or try to set `inner sep=0pt` in the star node (not sure it will work for small stars)

Comment: A quick test suggests to me that you cannot make the star smaller than `4mm` (smaller doesn't seem to change it. This in turn implies that circle has to be atleast `6mm` and the diamond at least `9mm`. You should use these sizes, and then use resizebox to change the total size or something similar.

Comment: @sweetyBaby: Please, try to respect the conventions of this community: Add full minimal compilable example documents (starting from `\documentclass`) so people don't have to guess what libraries are needed, and what `aux` is.

Comment: @Mythio this not true if `inner sep=0pt`.

Comment: @mwibrow True, but shes not using `inner sep` so given the code she provided, I think the restrictions I posted are accurate.

Comment: @Mythio: No, `inner sep` has a default value of `.3333em`, which causes the lower size limit of the shapes. Setting it to `0pt` allows any size, and is a much cleaner approach than using `\resizebox`

Comment: @Jake, I didnt know that it had a default value. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jake: why "cleaner"? May you develop or should I start a question?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: "cleaner" in the sense that setting the `inner sep` instead of using a `\resizebox` actually fixes the cause of the problem: You can't use the `\resizebox` approach if the star is part of a more complicated `tikzpicture` (or at least I wouldn't know how). I think sweetyBaby is trying to draw a flow chart, and this is just one of many objects in their picture, so `\resizebox` doesn't really help. Oh, and `\scalebox` will apply to the line widths as well, which will look odd.